# Object getter alias

Tags: javascript

My question is simple, how could i make aliases on object getters.

Example:

```
MyClass.prototype = {
    constructor: MyClass,
    get a() {
      // do stuff
    },
    get ab() {
      // do stuff
    },
    get abc() {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

Here, `a`, `ab` and `abc` does exactly the same, but it is mandatory to have these 3 different getters, or more precisely, it is mandatory to have 3 different names over the same functionality.

```
get a = ab = abc {

}
```

is obviously not working, neither does

```
get a() = ab() = abc() {

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `get ab() { a() }`, no?

Comment: If you're looking for the Javascript equivalent of the PHP magic class methods, I'm not sure they exist in the way you want then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get ab(){
    return this.a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an object literal, you cannot have a [self-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572) within one. Instead, [define the properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) programmatically - and you can indeed re-use the same property descriptor for each of them.

```
var desc = {
    configurable: true,
    get: function() {
      // do stuff
    }
};
Object.defineProperties(MyClass.prototype, {
    a: desc,
    ab: desc,
    abc: desc
});
```

Comment: Thanks, finally i did this way: https://github.com/jim-y/checkjs/blob/master/lib/check.js#L209